# Finding record in mysql table that has the highest value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to seach in my table named "map" to see which record has the highest value for "positionV".

For example if I had 5 records in "map" table and under "positionV" the values for each were, "3, 8, 9, 2, 10" I would wont it to output 10.

I am using PHP also by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM map
WHERE positionV = (SELECT MAX(positionV) FROM map)
```

Comment: Wow. For all those years I've been writing sub-queries for selecting MAX, MIN, etc. I didn't know it also worked like this. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, It keeps throwing up an error when I try to use this, even when I try the query in phpmyadmin it says "#1111 - Invalid use of group function".

Comment: @Stanni: Try it with a sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM map WHERE condition HAVING positionV = MAX(positionV)

Better to use having when doing aggregates.

Comment: @rojoca: You can't use aggregate functions in a WHERE clause, because the WHERE expressions are evaluated per row, not per group of rows.

Answer (score 0):

wouldnt

```
SELECT * FROM `map` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `positionV` DESC LIMIT 1
```

be sufficient?

whats the resource weight of the various methods given, anyone know?

Comment: If the table has an index on `positionV`, all of these queries will be optimized to just find the row with the highest value in the index (i.e. the last element in an ascending-sort index) and return the contents of that row. 1 page fetch for the index, 1 page fetch for the table row, assuming neither are in cache.

Comment: so
SELECT * FROM map WHERE condition HAVING positionV = MAX(positionV)
is more efficient?